# Changing content by manipulating the DOM w. Javascript vs. creating new HTML/CSS pages: which is more efficient?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, dom-manipulation

I'm building a very simple website with a few different sections like "about us", "pictures" and "contact".

I'd like to know which is more efficient (better performance and lower response time):

1.Using Javascript to manipulate the DOM and change the contents of the main section whenever the client clicks one of those item in the menu ("about us", "contact" etc) or...

2.Creating a new page (different HTML and CSS files) for each of these 4 or 5 sections I want the site to have?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For decisions such as this is why front-end frameworks like [Google Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/), [AngularJs](https://angularjs.org/), [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/), etc were created.

Obviously having a page change (as suggested in 2.) will be ***much slower*** than 1, since:

- The entire page has to reload (*dom is cleared, then re-constructed*)
- All shared styles/bindings have to be reapplied
- Overhead of making duplicate requests (*which introduces network latency to page load*)

However, though 1 may seem like an appealing design choice, performing un-optimized dom-manipulations (via jQuery) may actually hurt performance even more, since you'd introduce a ton of thrashing, and unnecessary middle steps.

---

Frameworks like **React**, handle this by using this by simulating a ***virtual DOM*** where:

- All operations are calculated in memory
- Changes are then optimized
- Only the diff of the changes is applied to the actual **DOM**

---

Modern web-component Frameworks (*like **Polymer**, **x-tag***) handle this by using declarative html syntax to bind data to HTML/JS behavior. The optimizations work by:

- Leverage shadow dom's which perform operations and styles ***only to the scope of that element***
- Statically binding all events to elements created (*no need for repetitive even callbacks*)
- Static referencing to all Id' elements in the component

  - This results in `O(1)` selection speed vs jQuery's `O(n)` approach
- Write once, use/customize everywhere approach

Answer (score 0):

As response time and performance are your main priorities. DOM manipulation will better suit your needs by allowing you to implement smooth transitions without a full page load.

As suggested above, you might benefit from using a framework that utilises virtual DOM. In which case, as your requirements are quit simple, a small component-based UI library like riotjs might suffice.

It might also be worth having a look at a single page website with sections that can be scrolled to manually or using a top nav. This would certainly meet your two main priorities.